# How to decompose $\mathbb{C}G$-modules into submodules?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

I'm currently having some trouble with a specific case of decomposing $\mathbb{C}G$-modules into irreducible submodules. The specific question is as follows:

> Let $G = \langle g, h \mid g^{4} = h^{2} = 1, gh = hg\rangle \cong C_{4} \times C_{2}$ be an abelian group of order 8, and let $V = \langle v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\rangle$ and $W = \langle w_{1}, w_{2} \rangle$ be the $\mathbb{C}G$-modules with $G$ action \begin{equation*} \begin{split}
> gv_{1} = v_{2},\quad gv_{2} &= -v_{1}, \quad gv_{3} = -v_{3}, \quad hv_{1} = -v_{1}, \quad hv_{2} = -v_{2}, \quad hv_{3} = v_{3} \\
> gw_{1} &= iw_{1}, \quad gw_{2} = -iw_{2}, \quad hw_{1} = -w_{1}, \quad hw_{2} = w_{2}
>  \end{split} \end{equation*} Decompose $V$ and $W$ into a direct sum of irreducible $\mathbb{C}G$-modules.

The reason I'm having issues with this question is that the lecture notes I'm working from only show how to deal with the situation in which $G$ is cyclic. Since the group $G$ here is abelian we can express both $V$ and $W$ as the direct sum of three and two 1-dimensional submodules respectively. In the cyclic case we simply find the eigenspaces of $[g]_{V}$ for a generator $g$, however what is the standard technique when we have more than one generator for the group? The eigenspaces of $[g]_{V}$ and $[h]_{V}$ are not the same (however the eigenspaces of $[g]_{W}$ and $[h]_{W}$ turn out to be the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take $V$. Then $x_1 = iv_1 + v_2, x_2 = -iv_1 + v_2, x_3 = v_3$ are three eigenvectors for both $g$ and $h$, so $V$ splits as direct sum of 3 simple $\Bbb CG$ module of dimension $1$. In fact, this is true for any abelian finite group, every irreducible representation is of dimension 1. For $W$ it is even easier since the action is directly by scalar multiplication, i.e $W \cong \Bbb C \langle w_1 \rangle \oplus \Bbb C \langle w_2 \rangle$.

In general, the standard technique is to use the character of representation. Of course, if you don't have character theory yet, the simplest for $G$ abelian is just to simultaneously diagonalize all the $\rho(g)$, and if $G$ is not abelian, try to find eigenvectors for $Z(G)$ and then try to see how $G$ is acting on these vectors, where I assumed $G$ was finite. A very good discussion for this is written in the first chapter of Fulton and Harris, *Representation theory, a first course*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was confused since the eigenspace of $[h]_{V}$ didn't match $[g]_{V}$; the key detail I missed was that an eigenvalue of $[h]_{V}$ had multiplicity two, hence any linear combination of $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ also make an eigenvector, in particular $(i,1,0)$ and $(-i,1,0)$ as you mentioned.

Comment: Sure you're welcome ! Indeed, any finite family of diagonalizable commuting endomorphisms $T_1, \dots, T_k$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. The first interesting example is of non-trivial $\Bbb CG$ module is $G = S_3$ with the permutation action on $V = \Bbb C^3$ and is worked the same way (by eigenspace and eigenvalue) in chapter $1$ of the book by Fulton and Harris. This is a very good method as the same method works for representations of Lie algebra.